# Why can only one action not see HTMLHelper?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm trying to make a simple asp.net-mvc application. I've made my model class and added it to the database. I used the built-in way to generate a controller with views using Entity Framework. But for some reason, when I try to view the Create page (and only the Create page, not the edit page!) I get a Null Reference Exception (Object reference not set to an instance of an object).

so here's my Create Action:

```
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

here's my Edit Action:

```
    public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
    {
        if (id == null)
        {
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
        SupplierCorrection supplierCorrection = db.SupplierCorrectionSet.Find(id);
        if (supplierCorrection == null)
        {
            return HttpNotFound();
        }
        return View(supplierCorrection);
    }
```

here's my create page:

```
@model FAIR.Data.Models.SupplierCorrection

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>SupplierCorrection</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

        @Html.Partial("_createEdit", Model)

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/SupplierCorrectionsCreateEdit.js"></script>
}
```

here's my edit page (the astute reader will notice it's very similar):

```
@model FAIR.Data.Models.SupplierCorrection

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>SupplierCorrection</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ID)

        @Html.Partial("_createEdit", Model)

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/Scripts/SupplierCorrectionsCreateEdit.js"></script>
}
```

and here's _createEdit:

```
@model FAIR.Data.Models.SupplierCorrection

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FAIRNumber, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FAIRNumber, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FAIRNumber, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Supplier, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Supplier, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Supplier, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Closed, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <div class="checkbox">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Closed)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Closed, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label col-md-2">Corrections Link</label>
    <div class="col-md-10">
        <input type="file" id="CorrectionsLinkFilePicker" onchange="CorrectionsLinkChosen();" />
        <input type="hidden" name="CorrectionsLink" id="CorrectionsLink" value="@Model.CorrectionsLink" />
        @if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(Model?.CorrectionsLink))
        {
            @:Currently: <a href="@Model.CorrectionsLink">@Model.CorrectionsLink</a>
        }
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CorrectionsLink, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    </div>
</div>
```

When I navigate to the Create page (again, not the edit page) it errors on line 24, where I do `Html.ValidationMesageFor(model => model.Closed,`... But if I remove that, it errors on the previous line. And so on until I'm down `using(Html.BeginForm())`. I guess as a stopgap I can just rewrite the page without using the `Html` object at all, but in case this happens again (or on a longer page) I'd like to know why in the world it suddenly went null.

Full Stack Trace:

```
   at ASP._Page_Views_SupplierCorrections__createEdit_cshtml.Execute() in C:\Users\ttm920632\Desktop\Repos\FAIR\FAIR\Views\SupplierCorrections\_createEdit.cshtml:line 24
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper.RenderPartialInternal(String partialViewName, ViewDataDictionary viewData, Object model, TextWriter writer, ViewEngineCollection viewEngineCollection)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model, ViewDataDictionary viewData)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Html.PartialExtensions.Partial(HtmlHelper htmlHelper, String partialViewName, Object model)
   at ASP._Page_Views_SupplierCorrections_Create_cshtml.Execute() in C:\Users\ttm920632\Desktop\Repos\FAIR\FAIR\Views\SupplierCorrections\Create.cshtml:line 18
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.RunPage()
   at System.Web.WebPages.StartPage.ExecutePageHierarchy()
   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage)
   at System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer, Object instance)
   at System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext viewContext, TextWriter writer)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1 filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext, ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult)
```

Comment: Can you show the full exception stacktrace?

Comment: Your action Edit returns an instance of a model. Create does not return a model.

Comment: @nbokmans question updated

Comment: As @Jasen says, there is no model being passed to the `Create` page (in your `Action`, you simply `return View()`).

Comment: It's not the model being null. On other pages successfully using `Html.EditorFor`, the model can be null without error. Not to mention, when I pare it down to the only instance of HtmlHelper being `using(Html.BeginForm())` it throws the error on that line, as I said in the question.

Comment: The stacktraces that come with exceptions thrown from views are sometimes not entirely accurate with line numbers. You are also creating a partial view which is also expecting `Model` but if it's null that's obviously not gonna work. Make sure the model isn't null and the crash won't happen 100%. If you want to create an empty instance of `SupplierCorrection` and use that as the model (which is common for `Create` actions) - `return View(new SupplierCorrection());`.

Comment: To put it this way: there are no other objects you refer to in your `Create` page that could be null, so nothing else other than the model can be the cause of the error.

Comment: As others said, "pass it a model" from the controller, you expect one with the `@model FAIR.Data.Models.SupplierCorrection` there...not passing one is the error - see the error, it expects one, but it is null if not passed.